# Adding an image to a PDF file using Python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to build a system where a user can verify a PDF report by signing it, so when a user is satisfied with the report they can run a script and it will add an image with their signature at the bottom. I have tried using `fitz` and `PyPDF2`. In case of `fitz` there is a problem installing the package on PyCharm and in case of `PyPDF2` I couldn't any relevant option. Can anybody please give me some suggestions?
(I am using Python 3.8)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about it, but I think [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) may help you:

```py
from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader

writer = PdfWriter()
reader = PdfReader("document1.pdf")
watermark_page = PdfReader("watermark.pdf").pages[0]

content_page = reader.pages[0]
content_page.merge_transformed_page(
            watermark_page,
            Transformation(),
        )
writer.add_page(content_page)

# finally, write "output" to document-output.pdf
with open("document-output.pdf", "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```

I think it's like a watermark, see [the manual](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/add-watermark.html#watermark-underlay) for a better idea.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Ujjwal. The only issue is watermark won't serve the purpose. But I will try looking for some functions available in the mentioned library.